# Substract first occurency from char*

Tags: arduino, esp32, arduino-esp32

I have this code on esp32 which get the return of command from an obd adapter

```
if (receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0) {
    char *p = buffer;
    Serial.print("3 - p:");
    Serial.println(p);
    Serial.print("31 - size of p : ");
    Serial.println(strlen(p));
            
    p = strstr(p, "43 ");
    Serial.print("32 - p:");
    Serial.println(p);
 }
```

My goal is to substract the first 3 chars "43 " from the buffer
And this is what I get in serial

```
3 - p:43 01 33 03 01 00 00 
>
31 - size of p : 23
32 - p:43 01 33 03 01 00 00 
>
33 - size of p : 23
```

How should I proceed to substract the first "43 " from the buffer ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just add an offset to the buffer pointer, so you're in effect *skipping three characters,* you should be fine:

```
if (receive(buffer, sizeof(buffer)) > 0) {
    char *p = buffer+3;
    Serial.print("3 - p:");
    Serial.println(p);
}
```

This should print

```
3 - p:01 33 03 01 00 00
```

Is this what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You can use strstr to check if buffer really contains (or starts with) "43 "
If it does, the returned pointer is set to the begin of "43 "

p+3 would point to the characters following "43 ", if this is what you call "subtracting".

If there's no "43 " in buffer, p is NULL, and p+3 points anywhere. Have fun.